# maximum recursion depth exceeded in sign language detection

Tags: python, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

```
frame = cv2.imread(r"/content/Dataset/test_set/G/1.png")
data = detect(frame)
```

I ran the above code and got a recursion error. The error is mentioned below. Help me out here.

```
RecursionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-0f8991388afb> in <module>
      1 frame = cv2.imread(r"/content/Dataset/test_set/G/1.png")
----> 2 data = detect(frame)

1 frames
... last 1 frames repeated, from the frame below ...

<ipython-input-26-d85ea30cf9d7> in detect(frame)
      1 frame = cv2.imread(r"/content/drive/MyDrive/My folder /IBM data set/conversation engine for deaf and dumb.zip")
      2 def detect(frame):
----> 3   data = detect(frame)

RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

I tried to test my model related to sign language detection and I got a recursion error. I was expcting a matric with numbers

Comment: You have the `detect` function immediately calling the `detect` function.  That is the very definition of a recursion error.  What did you expect that to do?

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply to my query. How can I solve this error?

Comment: I have no idea.  You have told us nothing about what you're trying to do, nor have you shown us any code that creates or uses a model.